# Getting `not assignable to type 'never'` Issue in My TypeScript Function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a function within a React functional component that was valid syntax in vanilla JavaScript (where there weren't type definitions, of course), but I'm having issues with it in TypeScript. This is the function in question:

```
  const getSelection = (id: number, selection: string) => {
    setAnswers((answers) => {
      const result = [...answers];
      result[id] = selection; // The error is here
      return result;
    });
  };
```

This is the error:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts
```

By the way `setAnswers` is where I use React's `useState()`:

```
  const [answers, setAnswers] = useState([]);
```

It's not clear to me how to resolve this issue. I have types assigned to each parameter being passed in, but that doesn't resolve the issue. I also tried temporarily making the type for both parameters `any` but that also didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: What is the type of the `setAnswers` function? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: See above details for additional information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Typescript can't infer the type of the items in the `asnwers` array. This is because when you initialize state as an empty array, there are not items to infer the type from. So typescript infers the state type as `never[]`, which isn't usable since nothing can ever be `never` except for `never`.

You can fix it by explicitly typing the call to `useState` with the type of that state, in this case `string[]`.

```
const [answers, setAnswers] = useState<string[]>([])
```

Then your code works as expected.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMDKMCGN1wC+cAZlBCHAORTo4DGMVAUMycgHaPAQdwBiECAAoAlImZw49XqngBtHB1QB3dFFQAaOBhgBBZWo0BdOAF4UGbHnQAeOVGAcA5vOMA+YW9GspM5fDO6DCY6AA26Ny85nDCwAAmAFxwHMggAEbq2hgRURzJDk7O4mbuElJSugaq6qjCwko1GiVlCJIVfrLwtKjIYfAW8gB0I41GqMYA3O0dPX0w8gmmFjmRMDwck3AA9NukwAAe6PEzFbQwyFB8c-3THYSid0TThEA)